# IDE pushing a non-existing file from my PC to Git

Tags: git, webstorm

I'm building a website with many videos in it.

After I did some changes in the code I committed it and pushed to Git. But I've got an error that my video is too large for git and then I deleted it from the folder. And now every time I'm trying to push like little change from HTML file git says that I'm trying to push big file that I've already deleted from my PC.

How can I fix that?

The error:
[image: error]

Literally the folder:
[image: Literally the folder]

**P.S.** I'm using WebStorm

Comment: File still exists in commits. You have to delete it form history

Comment: how can i do that? there is no delete button, pressing it on keyboard doesn't work too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history